Deleting model struct objectbox-go
When removing a model struct, I would expect the model to be removed from objectbox-model.json.
Unfortunately, it is still listed there. Resulting in errors in objectbox-model.go.
I have a simple structs.go file:
//go:generate go run github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/cmd/objectbox-gogen clean .
//go:generate go run github.com/objectbox/objectbox-go/cmd/objectbox-gogen

package main

// ToBeRemoved is an entity that should be removed from the objectbox-model.json.
// type ToBeRemoved struct {
//  Id   uint64 `objectbox:"id"`
//  Name string
// }

type ToBeKept struct {
    Id   uint64 `objectbox:"id"`
    Name string
}

And also an objectbox-model.json file:
{
  "_note1": "KEEP THIS FILE! Check it into a version control system (VCS) like git.",
  "_note2": "ObjectBox manages crucial IDs for your object model. See docs for details.",
  "_note3": "If you have VCS merge conflicts, you must resolve them according to ObjectBox docs.",
  "entities": [
    {
      "id": "1:3079339562650722594",
      "lastPropertyId": "2:305721489019317394",
      "name": "ToBeRemoved",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:480091436726252863",
          "name": "Id",
          "type": 6,
          "flags": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "2:305721489019317394",
          "name": "Name",
          "type": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2:3058164914484646824",
      "lastPropertyId": "2:8297323123436003017",
      "name": "ToBeKept",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "1:6680719812996421489",
          "name": "Id",
          "type": 6,
          "flags": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "2:8297323123436003017",
          "name": "Name",
          "type": 9
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "lastEntityId": "2:3058164914484646824",
  "lastIndexId": "",
  "lastRelationId": "",
  "modelVersion": 5,
  "modelVersionParserMinimum": 5,
  "retiredEntityUids": [],
  "retiredIndexUids": [],
  "retiredPropertyUids": [],
  "retiredRelationUids": [],
  "version": 1
}

Running go generate here, I would expect the entity "ToBeRemoved" to be removed from the objectbox-model.json
If you don't want to setup a project, I have pushed a simple reproduction project (including the two main files posted above) here:
https://github.com/jbleyaert/testobjectboxremoval
Other information related to this:
I found an issue on stackoverflow here:
Objectbox-go: deleting model class
Issue on Github here:
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-generator/issues/22
Also the PR of the fix here:
https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-generator/pull/29
Unfortunately, even though I am using the latest version which includes this PR, I can still reproduce this.
Am I doing something wrong?

I'm not "just" posting a link. These are github issues that are relevant to the question. There is also enough information and questions in my post above. Would you expect me to post every file of my reproduction project so you can copy paste and test it? Thanks for clarifying.

The issue has been closed and the PR was merged years ago? Maybe you want to double check your assumptions and start over with a new question?

I double checked, that's why I posted a reproduction project and not just assumptions.

To respond to your comment: You've posted a link to your GitHub, which could disappear overtime. If that happens then the entire question is useless

We opened an internal issue to investigate... In the meantime, please consider to improve your question to meet StackOverflow's guidelines?

Thanks Markus. I have improved the question by adding 2 code snippets to the post.
